# Iterate in specific portion of numpy array and add values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Probably this is a very easy and silly fix, but I cannot think of anyway to solve this issue.

I have a three column array with 2000 elements like so where each column represent x, y, z coordinates.

```
Final_array =np.zeros([2000,3])
```

Through some `for` loops I am trying to populate this array's columns. I was able to populate the first 1000 rows of the y values (second column) with the information of another array `y_coords1`, but I don't know how to populate the remaining 1000 bottom rows with another array `y_coords2`. Can someone please help?

```
# putting y values
for y in range(len(y_coords1)):  
    Final_array[y, 1] = y_coords1[y]
for w in Final_array[999:2000]:
    for y in range(len(y_coords2)):
        Final_array[y,1] = y_coords2[y]

print(Final_array)
```

I have tried some variations on the for loops but I get errors.

Comment: you can stack y_coords and then cast in FinalArray :`FinalArray[:,1]=np.concatenate([y_coords1 ,y_coords2 ],axis=0)` maybe?

Comment: Thank you very much! As I said I knew it was something silly with an easy fix. I guess I was trying to keep that approach of the for loops instead of thinking more logically!

Comment: as a general advice, avoid loops until you have no option, but beside that remember that indexation in numpy arrays is very ussefull, if you need some help let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a different approach to answer this question, but the solution provided by Ulises Bussi worked to solve the issue

```
FinalArray[:,1] = np.concatenate([y_coords1 ,y_coords2 ],axis=0)
```